# listen for fulscreenChange event in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listener, fullscreen

I am using a button to slip a DOM element into fullscreen mode using the fullscreen API. this part works as expected. The issue iss that when i exit fullscreen mode i need to listen for the fullscreen change event and resize the dom element. Here is what i am currently trying:

Html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="changeVideoSize(4)">Fullscreen</button>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.changeVideoSize = function(size) {

    switch (size) {

    case 1:
        resizeDiv("swfStage" , "320px" , "240px");
        break;
    case 2:
        resizeDiv("swfStage" ,"500px" ,"375px" );
        break;
    case 3:
        resizeDiv("swfStage" , "700px" , "525px" );
    break;
    case 4:
        fullScreenToggle("swfStage");
        resizeDiv("swfStage",getWidth(),getHeight());
        break;
    default:
        $scope.changeVideoSize(1);
    }

};

function fullScreenToggle(domId) {

    // full-screen available?
    if (
        document.fullscreenEnabled || 
        document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || 
        document.mozFullScreenEnabled ||
        document.msFullscreenEnabled
    ) 
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById(domId);
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }   
    }


}

// Events
$scope.$on("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
    console.log("fullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
$scope.$on("mozfullscreenchange", function(e) {
    console.log("mozfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
$scope.$on("webkitfullscreenchange", function(e) {
    console.log("webkitfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
$scope.$on("msfullscreenchange", function(e) {
    console.log("msfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
```

I did not include the logic for the resize div function but it does work. My issue is that when I call fullScreenToggle() specifically elem.requestFullscreen() in any of the variations i would expect to see a fullscreen change event fired ... but it either is not ... or im not listening to it correctly ..

Comment: declare a var called `isFullscreen` and have it initially equal to `false`. On the `fullscreenchange` event, change the value like `isFullscreen = !isFullscreen;` You can now just check that var to see if it is fullscreen or not

Comment: i guess my issue is not so much getting into fullscreen ... its that i need to listen to that event so that when i exit fullscreen i can resize the DIV element properly

Comment: Ahh, I see. Jason is right then. `$on` listens for angular events fired from `$broadcast`.

Comment: so how do i listen to it correctly? do i add a listener to the template or can i still do it somehow from within the controller (prefered method)

Comment: Well since Angular uses jQuery, I believe you can do something like this in the controller: http://pastie.org/9059230

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.$on` is listening for angular events, you need to watch for the fullscreenchange event on the element you are requesting full screen for.

Comment: something like this  in angular controller:         
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {};  or will i need to put that listener in my template and have it call a function in my angular controller?

Comment: To be re-usable you could create a directive that you just place once that would then broadcast the event to the $rootScope that you could then listen for in your controller.  The directive could handle the browser idiosyncrasies and just provide the `fullscreenchange` name for the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to the fullscreenchange event, you should do it in a directive, not in a controller.

I've made a library that wraps this behaviour in an angular way [angular-screenfull](https://github.com/hrajchert/angular-screenfull)

Hope it helps!